# java - Extraordinary NumberFormatException

Tags: java

So I have this line of code

```
w=(char)Integer.parseInt(new String(num,0,fidx));
```

Where `w` is `unsigned` short (aka char), num is character array, and `fidx` is the number of characters.
And somehow I get this error

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "1065"
```

I tried to check fidx and num, but nothing...

Any ideas?

**Edit:** And if it help I runned this code on android.

Comment: Instead of trying to do everything in a single line. Why don't you try to separate it in multiple lines to see what's going on

Comment: I suspect whitespace or non-printing characters. You could look at the `char[]` to see what you have ended up with...

Comment: I tried with `char[] num = new char[] {'1','0','6','5'};` and did not encounter an error.

Comment: Separate this out into several lines. Check what you're string is evaluating to first. Ensure there's no spaces. Check its length, etc. The string value cannot be parsed by parseInt as an Integer, so the problem is the string that you're trying to pass in.

Comment: @ManoDestra I have already done this, I also checked char codes, but still....

Comment: So I cut `parseInt()` method from source code, paste it in my code and changed error messages. It says that there is something wrong with digit 5

Comment: @MkKm maybe using a debugger would have been a smarter choice... It's a whitespace issue - use `trim()`.

Comment: White space would be my guess too. I assume it's 1065 + a space. That's why I was saying to output the length. If it says 1065 and the length is not 4, then you have a problem.

Comment: @ManoDestra Length of the character array and the String object is equal to 4. I viewed parseInt method's source code and wrote different error messages. And I think parseInt just don't stop at the end of the string, thats all.